# How does REACT call a Private API Gateway?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-api-gateway

According to AWS documentation, if you want to make your API Gateways private you need to put them behind a VPC Endpoint and either access them using Private DNS or pass the ID of the API Gateway as a header in the request.

```
curl -H'x-apigw-api-id:«gateway-id»' https://«vpce-id».execute-api.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/my/path
```

That works great, until I point a React app at it and React automatically sends a preflight request (OPTIONS) and that request doesn't have the `x-apigw-api-id` header in it and a 403 is returned and my React app breaks.

Is there a way to configure React to include a custom header in preflight requests?  Is there a way to configure the VPC endpoint to approve the preflight?

Comment: React doesn't send anything. It's a frontend component framework.

Comment: Preflight requests are sent by the browser to respect CORS policies of servers the requests should be sent to.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of a request being made within your React app.